# Importing vss-web-extension-sdk modules in Angular-CLI components

Tags: typescript, azure-devops, angular-cli, vssdk

I'm trying to create a VSTS/TFS extension which is based on an angular/cli app.
I've created a new app using *ng new* and it compiles and serves fine.
Now, my problem is referencing and consuming the vss sdk in my components.

I've made some changes based on the recommendations made [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40752520/using-vss-web-extension-sdk-in-angular-2):

1. Added "vss-web-extension-sdk" to package.json dependencies:

   "dependencies": {
       "@angular/animations": "^4.0.0",
       "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
       "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
       "@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
       "@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
       "@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
       "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
       "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
       "@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
       "core-js": "^2.4.1",
       "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
       "vss-web-extension-sdk": "^2.117.0",
       "zone.js": "^0.8.4"   },
2. Added the following typings.json file:

   ```
   {
     "globalDependencies": {
     "jquery": "registry:dt/jquery#1.10.0+20160929162922",
     "knockout": "registry:dt/knockout#0.0.0+20160914182733",
     "q": "registry:dt/q#0.0.0+20161004185634",
     "require": "registry:dt/require#2.1.20+20160919185614",
     "tfs": "npm:vss-web-extension-sdk/typings/tfs.d.ts",
     "vss": "npm:vss-web-extension-sdk/typings/vss.d.ts"
     }
   }
   ```
3. Imported "VSS/Context"

   import * as VSS_Context from 'VSS/Context';

At this point the app builds with no errors, but when I try to consume the imported module, I get a build error: ***Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'VSS/Context'***

This is how I consume the imported module:

```
export class AppComponent {

title = 'app';

    constructor()
    {
        var ctx = VSS_Context.getDefaultWebContext();
    }
}
```

The entire app can be found at https://github.com/shaycy/tfs-ng-app

Comment: Try to refer to this article https://github.com/Microsoft/vss-web-extension-sdk

Comment: I've seem this article. It shows how to use the vss sdk from within the html but I could not find an example of using it from a .ts component.

Comment: I can build it with TSC command, but can't build through ng build command, what's the result of you?

Comment: I tried building that single component with tsc (command: _tsc src\app\app.component.ts_) and got the following errors: src/app/app.component.ts(2,1): error TS1148: Cannot compile modules unless the '--module' flag is provided.
src/app/app.component.ts(2,27): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
src/app/app.component.ts(4,30): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'VSS/Context'.
src/app/app.component.ts(6,1): error TS1205: Decorators are only available when targeting ECMAScript 5 and higher.

Comment: @starain-MSFT How did you build it? How can I build it through the _ng build_ command?